# Validar senha com JS usando class

Tags: javascript

Estou com problema com este código para validar o campo de 'password',  o campo 'user' tá indo de boa, mas da senha não vai

```js
class Validate {
    constructor() {
        this.form = document.querySelector('.login-form');
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            this.handleSubmit(e);
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const validInputs = this.inputsOK();
        const validPassword = this.passwordValidate();

        if (validInputs && validPassword) {
            alert('Login successfully');
            this.form.submit();
        }
    }

    inputsOK() {
        let valid = true;

        for (let errorText of this.form.querySelectorAll('.error')) {
            errorText.remove();
        }

        for (let field of this.form.querySelectorAll('.validate')) {
            const label = field.previousElementSibling.innerText;
            if (!field.value) {
                this.createError(field, `Field "${label}" cannot be empty`);
                valid = false;
            }

            if (field.classList.contains('user')) {
                if (!this.userValidate(field)) valid = false;
            }

            if (field.classList.contains('password')) {
                if (this.passwordValidate()) valid = false;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }

    userValidate(field) {
        const user = field.value;
        let valid = true;

        if (!user.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/g)) {
            this.createError(field, 'User must be letters end/or numbers');
            valid = false;
        }

        if (user.length < 3 || user.length > 12) {
            this.createError(field, 'User must be between 3 or 12 characters');
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    passwordValidate() {
        const password = this.form.querySelector('.password');
        let valid = true;

        if (password.value.length < 6 || password.value.length > 12) {
            this.createError(
                field,
                'Password must be between 3 or 12 characters'
            );
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    createError(field, msg) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = msg;
        div.classList.add('error');
        field.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);
    }
}

const validateLogin = new Validate();
```

```html
<body>
        <main>
            <div class="wrapper-container">
                <section class="form-container">
                    <header class="header">
                        <h2>Login</h2>
                        <h4>Enter your User and Password to access account.</h4>
                    </header>
                    <form
                        action="./pages/login-done.html"
                        method="get"
                        class="login-form"
                    >
                        <div class="user-container">
                            <label for="user">User</label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="user validate"
                                placeholder="Type your user"
                                id="user"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="password-container">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                class="password validate"
                                placeholder="Type your password"
                                id="password"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="button-container">
                            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="recovery-password-container">
                        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <div class="ilustration-container">
                    <img
                        src="./assets/undraw_version_control_re_mg66.svg"
                        alt="Image of the someone using a Laptop"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

executei seu projeto e acho que encontrei a solução, vou colocar algumas observações abaixo:

1º Ponto é na função handleSubmit - Você estava validando o password duas vezes, você executava a função inputsOk que dentro dela já chamava a validação do password, e depois executava a função passwordValidate que validava novamente o password, fiz algumas alterações na função handleSubmit e ficou assim:

```
     handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const validInputs = this.inputsOK();

        if (validInputs) {
            alert('Login successfully');
            this.form.submit();
        }
    }
```

2º Ponto é na função inputsOK - Nesta função quando você está testando se a lista de classes do field contém a classe password, se tiver você chama a função passwordValidate e deveria passar como argumento o field, porém você não estava passando o field passava somente na função userValidate. Outra coisa é que para saber se a validação falhou você deveria negar o retorno da função com o sinal de ! igual você fez na função userValidate, segue abaixo como ficou a função inputsOk:

```
      inputsOK() {
        let valid = true;

        for (let errorText of this.form.querySelectorAll('.error')) {
            errorText.remove();
        }

        for (let field of this.form.querySelectorAll('.validate')) {
            const label = field.previousElementSibling.innerText;
            if (!field.value) {
                this.createError(field, `Field "${label}" cannot be empty`);
                valid = false;
            }

            if (field.classList.contains('user')) {
                if (!this.userValidate(field)) valid = false;
            }

            if (field.classList.contains('password')) {
                if (!this.passwordValidate(field)) valid = false;
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

O último ponto é na função passwordValidate - Primeira ponto é que não estava recebendo o field como argumento, segundo você estava fazendo um query selector desnecessário dentro do form pois não estava recebendo o field, sendo assim a função ficou assim:

```
     passwordValidate() {
      const password = this.form.querySelector('.password');
      let valid = true;

      if (password.value.length < 6 || password.value.length > 12) {
          this.createError(
              field,
              'Password must be between 3 or 12 characters'
          );
          valid = false;
      }

      return valid;
    }
```

Pequena observação: Na frase de erro do password está dizendo que o password dee conter entre 3 a 12 carácteres, porém a validação está entre 6 a 12, ai fica a seu critério, alterar a frase ou a validação.

Abraços, espero ter ajudado.